# CSS center position absolute image internet explorer

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

I have the following css which in chrome and safari centers an absolutely positioned image

```
.productImg {
     width: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -50%;
}
```

However in internet explorer 7 this doesn't center the image. Instead the image stays on the left side of the container div. My question is, how can I make my script above work in ie7?

Comment: Ah, the reminiscing sound of "how can I make this work in IE7." Not a definite duplicate, but maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6/why-doesnt-the-percentage-width-child-in-absolutely-positioned-parent-work-in-i?rq=1 can help.

Comment: The problem is that I already have a fixed height/width for the parent div and the problem still persists. The answer to the other thread was that the parent div had no fixed height/width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your image is the width of its container and you want it centered, why not just align it to the left?

```
.productImg 
{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Cool. I wish I had the time to figure out why IE7 interpreted your css differently, but it might not be such a big deal given IE7's plummeted market share: http://theie7countdown.com/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;`? This is the best way to center horizontally.

For this you should wrap a div something like this:

```
<div class="hCenter">
<div class="productImg"></div>
</div>
```

Then css would be as following:

```
.hCenter{
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
productImg{
/*now you can align position absolute*/
/*other code in here*/
}
```

**Edit**

If you still want to be aligned horizontally centered with absolute position, you could do like this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7CdQT/)

```
.productImg {
     width: 50%;
     position: absolute;
     right: 25%; /* half of the width percentage*/
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**Edit 1**

If your parent div is positioned absolutely, then you don't need to set `position: absolute` your `.productImg`. Just add `margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;`

Comment: Did exactly as suggested above and still same problem.

Comment: My parent div is relative positioned, so I just applied the .productImg code above to my img class. But still aligned to the left

Comment: Did you have applied margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; to your parent div?

Comment: Yea, for some reason the fiddle works in ie7 and another test document I create also centers the image, but the live site I'm working on just won't change for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to center the parent div.

```
div {
    width: 300px /* give div a width */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```