# Expand parent div when height of position:absolute child div is increased

Tags: jquery, css

I have a parent div and 2 child div's.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child1 col-2"></div>
    <div class="child2 col-10"></div>
</div>
```

The **child1** is absolutely positioned and contains collapsible items. When I expand the collapsible items in **child1** its height increases. How do I increase the height of the **parent** div and/or **child2** div when the height of **child1** increases after the page has loaded?

Comment: Absolutely positioning removes the item from the page flow, removing this positioning solves your problem. Your question needs more context. Why is **child1** absolutely positioned, what are you aims and constraints?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the percentage width child in absolutely positioned parent work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6/why-doesnt-the-percentage-width-child-in-absolutely-positioned-parent-work)

Comment: I've used child 1 as absolutely positioned because it has been added to common elements of the project (python/django templating). Is there any way to increase height of child 2 according to change in height of child 1 after the page has been loaded?

Answer (score 0):

**Your first child (child1) position is absolute, you need to calculate the height of the first div and assigned the top value for second div**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/73URF/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child1 col-2">Child1<br/>test1
        <a class="collapse" href="#">collapse</a>
        <div class="insideDiv">
            test inside
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child2 col-10">Child2</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.child1 {
    position:absolute;
}
.child2 {
    position:relative;
}
.insideDiv {
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var child1Height = $(".child1").height();
$(".child2").css('top' , child1Height); 

$(".child1 .collapse").click(function(){
    $(".insideDiv").slideDown(function(){        
        var countHeight = $(".child1").height();
        $(".child2").css('top' , countHeight);    
    });
})
```